# Creating a PDF TextField in a form with several lines using borb

Tags: borb

I am trying to create a pdf form using borb where the TextField has
several lines and possibly prefilled with a multiline string showing several of these lines.

I could not find anything in the docs about this. The [online book](https://github.com/jorisschellekens/borb-examples#table-of-contents) does to seem to have any examples of this.

Borb might not be the right tool for this, but I do not need the extensive control perhaps offered by other tools such as ReportLab. I quite like the level of documentation and the style of borb and this is the only feature I miss.

Here is a [file](https://files.fm/f/nnzngy7w5) I made using "Master PDF Editor", showing how I would like the pdf form to behave.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the `TextArea` class might do what you want. It's not covered by the borb documentation but can be imported from the same namespace as `TextField`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

A minimal example inspired by @CthulhuStig that does what I wanted:

```py
from borb.pdf.canvas.color.color import HexColor
from borb.pdf.canvas.layout.forms.text_area import TextArea
from borb.pdf.canvas.layout.page_layout.multi_column_layout import SingleColumnLayout
from borb.pdf.canvas.layout.page_layout.page_layout import PageLayout
from borb.pdf.document.document import Document
from borb.pdf.page.page import Page
from borb.pdf.pdf import PDF

# create Document
doc: Document = Document()

# create Page
page: Page = Page()

# add Page to Document
doc.add_page(page)

# set a PageLayout
layout: PageLayout = SingleColumnLayout(page)

layout.add(
                    TextArea(field_name="name",
                            value="content1\ncontent2",
                            number_of_lines=25,
                            font_color=HexColor("#003366")))

with open("borb_form.pdf", "wb") as pdf_file_handle:
    PDF.dumps(pdf_file_handle, doc)
```